# unstandardized coefficient B value 2.314E-005 in multivariate regression analysis

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, linear

I do multivariate regression analysis for a dependent variable. unstandardized coefficient B for one of the independent variables was  2.314E-005 ,standardized coefficient Beta was 0.051, CI (0.000- 0.000), p=0.409. i want to know what is the this abnormal value of unstandardized coefficient 2.314E-005 means ?

Comment: What's abnormal about 2.314E-005?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 3):

2.314E-005 is simply 2.314 x 10^-5

It's written like that because that's how most programming languages interpret [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

[image]